# Identify a scifi novel where a man travels to a distant colony with insectoid natives and problems due to earthquakes

Tags: story-identification

Okay I read this book a while back, it wasn't a particularly good read, but I can not remember their titles.

The first book I read about 10 years ago. It centers on a male protagonist who travels to a far off space colony to help out with some problems.

When he gets there, he finds that the place is ravaged by earthquakes and tectonic activity.

Initially, when the humans landed, they had help from these giant bug creatures. I think they were described as telepathic doodlebugs or slugs. I can't remember for sure, but I think the humans used them to help carry heavy stuff.

At one point humans were able to build a hydroelectric dam but the tectonic activity caused the dam to crack, and a flood came down and wiped out a good deal of the insect people.

I guess this guy shows up and realizes that the the earthquakes are a response to human settlement or whatever, and the only way to make peace with the insect people is to live a minimalist lifestyle. No electricity.

Actually now that I think about it, there was a line where he's trying to explain to one of the bugs that humans will do whatever it takes to get electricity.

The bug people just eat grass and chill all day. They're not interested in manipulating the environment.

I thought this book might be Deathworld, but there's no way that is. I was able to read a few chapters and it can't be. This book started out with the guy video-conferencing his son from a space station, and commenting on how much his son had aged over the years.

Anyways sorry if I'm too vague but this is all I can remember. Thanks if any one can help.

Comment: If these are two separate unrelated books, they should be two separate unrelated questions.